# Can not find namespace 'angular'

Tags: angularjs, angular, angular-cli-v6

I have an hybrid angular app with Angularjs 1.5.8 and angular 5.2.9.  I had followed the steps from the [Upgrading from AngularJS to Angular](https://angular.io/guide/upgrade). It is working perfectly fine.
However, after I upgrade angular 5.2.9 to angular 6.0.1, I  am getting error during `ng serve`.

```
error TS2503: Cannot find namespace 'angular'
```

As mentioned in the [Upgrading from AngularJS to Angular](https://angular.io/guide/upgrade) I have declared  'angular'

```
declare var angular: angular.IAngularStatic;
```

While upgrading angular from 5.2.9 to 6.0.1, I followed the steps from [Angular Update Guide - 5.2 -> 6.0 for Advanced Apps](https://update.angular.io/)

How can I resolve this problem?

Comment: In WebStorm 2019.1 I noted this same error, using Angular 7. As mentioned earlier by Patricio:
try `npm install --save-dev @types/angular` and add the "angular" type to tsconfig.app.json (the app specific one, not the global one). `... "types": [ "angular" ],
`

Answer (score 6):

try `npm install --save-dev @types/angular`

if not try the following: 
you need to add "angular" types to tsconfig.json

```
...
    "types": [
        "angular"
    ],
```

Comment: I have @types/angular installed as well as I have tsconfig.json similar to what you have  mentioned

Comment: try this **declare var angular: any;** instead of declare var angular: angular.IAngularStatic;

Comment: I tried your suggestion, but still it was throwing the same error. However, import {} from '@types/angular'; fixed the error.

Comment: I already had @types/angular installed, but I had to add "types": ["angular"] to my tsconfig.json file. When upgrading from angular 4 to angular 5, and typescript 2.3.4 to typescript 2.5.2

Comment: As [Jaap Reitsma](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7463077/jaap-reitsma) said in the comment on the original post, this change should be made in the app specific tsconfig. This is what got it work for me